# FileSystemWatcher Events in IDE

Tags: c#, .net, filesystemwatcher

FileSystemWatcher provide us different kind of events from changed to deleted. I was wondering why I'm getting deleted event whenever I used visual studio 2005 to edit a file and changed event if I'm using notepad or notepad++ and other editor?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Standard operation for programs that want to avoid losing everything:

1. Rename original file
2. Create new file with original name
3. Write and close file
4. No problems: delete file from step 1

If something goes wrong, the renamed file is restored.  Your other editor would corrupt the original if something goes wrong while writing.

Comment: Sorry Hans but your comments does not answer my question. I asked why FileSystemWatcher instance is firing deleted event if I "edited" a specific file using VS2005. I was expecting that it would fire Changed event. 

Anyways thanks your comments.

Comment: hmm thanks I got your point. I'm getting a temporary file on deleted event but I never get the changed event.

Comment: Review steps 1 through 3, nothing is getting changed.  The temporary file got created at step 1.